# Xcode iOS 7 with Urban Airship Framework: Semantic Issue; Reference… is Ambiguous

Tags: ios, xcode, urbanairship.com

I'm implementing the Urban Airship framework into an iPhone app (iOS 7) in Xcode 5.0.2.

Unfortunately, I keep hitting a roadblock. I have one error when attempting to build the project:

File: UAMapPresentationController.h:

`- (void)moveSpanToCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location;`

Error:

`Semantic Issue: Reference to CLLocationCoordinate2D is ambiguous`

What is odd is that I've sent this project to a fellow developer for him to look at it, but he gets no errors when building. Obviously there is some issue on my local machine or with my framework references or something.

I have not been able to find much discussion about this type of error message so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of that framework, and using the correct code for that version?

Comment: Yes, I re-downloaded the framework from UA to be sure. I copied and pasted code for the AppDelegate.m file, and that code is causing no errors. I haven't touched this file that is generating the error.

Comment: try making a new project and putting the code in there.

Comment: This is a new project; it has happened multiple times.